# Framework (RestKit) not compatible with armv7s

Tags: iphone, xcode, restkit

When I try to archive my project for the iPhone 5 (armv7s), it comes with an error which states that RestKit is not compatible with the armv7s architecture.

In this project I'm using an old version from RestKit, version 0.9. This version is by default not capable to work with armv7s. Is there a way to setup the RestKit project (version 0.9) to support armv7s.

I've tried to add armv7s to the valid architectures for the RestKit project and changed the architectures to support armv6 and armv7. Unfortunately that didn't work out.

Of course I can setup the project with the latest version of RestKit. Only this will take a lot of time, since the core has been updated a lot of times.

Another question, would the app (build for armv6 and armv7) which is currently in the store, work on the iPhone 5 (armv7s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unwilling to update to the latest (compatable) version, you would be better off, leaving the valid architectures as 6&7, the processor on the iPhone 5 is backwards compatable with the older architectures. The only drawback is you won't get any specific optimisations for the iPhone 5' armv7s processor.

Comment: Thanks, I submitted the app with only armv7 support. So now it's available from the iPhone 3gs to the iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking how the RestKit guys did it in this commit: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/commit/29ba601cfc38560be923f57fba545881d0789ea5

and then trying to work out a way from there to get it done for your specific circumstances.

Might not be a complete solution but it's definitely a good hint.