# iOS API Kal doesn't compile with iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ios-simulator

I'm using the iOS Kal API in my project. When I try to compile and run the project with my iPhone 4S or the iPhone 5 Simulator, it works perfectly but when I try it with a real iPhone 5, I get this error :

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/sebliberal/Dropbox/Appli FACE 06/Version iPhone/FACE06/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers/libOAuth.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I already searched for this error and I set YES for Build Active Architecture Only but I still have the error.. What's the problem ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this:
[Framework (RestKit) not compatible with armv7s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493241/framework-restkit-not-compatible-with-armv7s)

This:
[AdMob ARMv7s support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569457/admob-armv7s-support)

or This:
[iOS - file does not contain an armv7s slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737736/ios-file-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice)

Or one of many answers on SO and the internet.

The short answer is you need to either update your library or remove armv7s from your supported architectures.